# Drupal module updates failing through administrative interface after update to 7.50

Tags: 7, updating

So, I just updated my site to Drupal 7.50, and in addition to being informed of a host of modules that weren't properly uninstalled, it seems that I can no longer update modules through the administrative interface. I have a long list of module updates and it will be annoying to do all of them manually.

So is there some setting that changed? Or how can I get back to being able to update modules through the admin UI. I've tried a few at a time, as well as one at a time. I get the following warning after trying to update

```
The file could not be created.
https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/google_analytics-7.x-2.3.tar.gz could not be saved to temporary://update-cache-d103ec38/google_analytics-7.x-2.3.tar.gz.
The file could not be created.
https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/webform-7.x-4.14.tar.gz could not be saved to temporary://update-cache-d103ec38/webform-7.x-4.14.tar.gz.
Downloading updates failed:

Failed to download google_analytics from https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/google_analytics-7.x-2.3.tar.gz
Failed to download webform from https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/webform-7.x-4.14.tar.gz
```

Comment: `in addition to being informed of a host of modules that weren't properly uninstalled` Did you place all those modules back into the modules folder (via FTP or Drush) and then uninstall them?

Comment: No, not yet because some of those modules were custom from a previous site maintainer that I don't have access to. I will have to manually remove them from the db. Are you saying that the update mechanism is failing because of the improperly removed modules? this wasn't an issue previously

Comment: perhaps, I had client that had [104 modules](http://eisdev1.com/Report.html) but I never tried installing anything when I was getting the warnings, so I can't tell you for sure.

Comment: We have 90 something modules, I can track down all but some of the custom modules. I have to go back through old site backups to see if I can track down some of the missing modules...what a pain.

Comment: `what a pain` I feel ya. Hhhhmmm `The file could not be created.` this makes me believe that it could be a folder permission issue. Is your server runing on Ubuntu? If yes, make sure the folder owner is `www-data`

Comment: Are you not using Drush + git to update and push changes to a repo? The general census of the community at large is to avoid that admin updater as it has always been error prone. You can have Drush update one or more modules with a single command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely a problem with your file permissions. A quick test on simplytest.me showed that module installation is not broken in 7.50.

I would try to check the file_temporary_path variable under:

"Administrator -> Configuration -> Media -> File System"

And see that the web server can write to the configured directory.

If my assumption is correct, then also all other file uploads will fail, so it might be a good idea to test uploading an image to an article, too.

Comment: this was it. thnx.